# What does this specific regex do?

Tags: regex

The regex is:

```
/^\/node?(?:\/(\d+)(?:\.\.(\d+))?)?/
```

I can understand that `/` in the beginning and the end are regex delimiters, also `^\/node` is for a string starting with `/node` What's happening after that beats me!

Comment: I recommend to go through a regex tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html. It's all explained there.

Comment: Literally any article, tutorial or cheat sheet about regexes tell what those symbols mean. Which part exactly is unclear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into getting a tool like RegexBuddy. It will explain everything in a given regex, as well as how it compiles and how it branches.

Assuming PCRE or similar:

```
   /                    //begin
        ^               //start of string
        \/              //literal /
        node?           //I assume node is optional, normally it'd be (node)?
                        //? makes the previous expression optional
        (
             ?:         //non-capturing group (think of it like dont capture <this>)
             \/         //literal /
             (\d+)      // one or more digits, 0-9
             (
                  ?:    // another non-capturing group
                  \.\.  // literal ..
                  (\d+) // one or more digits 0-9
             )
             ?         // optional once more
        )
        ?              // make the previous group optional
    /                  // end
```

Comment: `?:` is not a negative lookahead. It's a non-capturing group. I don't know of any regex engine/env. using `?:` as negative lookahead...

Comment: @Jerry whoops, that's `?!`. my bad.

Answer (score 3):

`?` anything following this is "optional"

`(?:` non-capturing group

`\/` escaped /

`(\d+)` -more than 1 digit - also in a capture group "()"

`(?:` again

`\.` - escaped .

`\.` - again

`(\d+)` - same as before

`)?)?` - not sure - what flavour of regex is this?

Comment: hmm, apparently we're working from different flavours of regex.

Comment: @Hiroto yes to me ?? is "previous is optional"... OP did not specify

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, the `/` at the start are pattern delimiters. Lets remove those for simplicity

```
^\/node?(?:\/(\d+)(?:\.\.(\d+))?)?
```

The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. This is a group that does not get grabbed into a match group. This is an optimisation, let's remove the `?:` to make the pattern clearer.

```
^\/node?(\/(\d+)(\.\.(\d+))?)?
```

The `\` is an escape character, so `\/` is actually just a `/` but as these denote the start and end of the pattern then need to be escaped. The `.` matches (almost) any character so it needs to be escaped too.

The `?` makes the receding pattern optional, so `()?` means whatever is in the brackets appears zero or one times.

- `^` denotes the start of the string
- `\/node?` matches `/node` or `/nod`
- `\/(\d+)` matches `/` followed by one or more digits (the `\d+`). The digits are captured into the first match group
- `(\.\.(\d+))?` matches `..` followed by one or more digits (the `\d+`). The digits are captured into the second match group

Comment: Excellent answer, I like how you removed the stuff that did not apply to how the pattern matches.